how to delete lines in python canvas one by one
I would like to delete line one by one after created but only last line delete. Here is my code:
import os
from tkinter import *
os.system("cls||clear")

def on_click():
    global lines,item
   canvas.delete(lines.pop())    

def first_motion(event):
    global x_fm,y_fm
    x_fm = event.x
    y_fm = event.y

def second_motion(event):
    global x_fm,y_fm,x_sm,y_sm,x,lines,item
    x_sm = event.x
    y_sm = event.y

    lines = []
    item = canvas.create_line(x_fm,y_fm, x_sm,y_sm,width=5)
    lines.append(item)
    print(lines)
    lbl.config(text=f"line is created: x1={x_fm},y1={y_fm},x2={x_sm},y2={y_sm}"
           ,fg="maroon")

def motion(event):
    x_y_lbl.config(text="(x=%s y=%s)" % (event.x, event.y)
             ,font=("times",10),fg="dark blue")    

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400,bg="khaki2")
canvas.pack()   

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', first_motion)
canvas.bind('<Button-3>', second_motion)
canvas.bind('<Motion>',motion)

Button(root,text="Delete Line",command=on_click).pack()
Button(root, text="Exit", command=quit).pack()

lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()

x_y_lbl = Label(root)
x_y_lbl.place(x=70,y=430)

root.geometry("650x500")
root.mainloop()

run the program and click first left mouse button on canvas then right mouse button to create a line between clicks and repeat the click to create more lines then delete the lines you will see only last line will delete. Please let me know the problem and remedy you suggest.
Thanks

In second_motion, you create a new, empty list each time with lines = []. Move that to the start of your program so the list is only created once.

Hello my friend, your solution works. Thanks for your help

line 9, in on_click
canvas.delete(lines.pop())
^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: pop from empty list
